# Behaviour JqueryValidator and bootstrap 3, using Glyphicons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, glyphicons

I'm trying to dig into the use of validators with bootstrap 3 and glyphicons.

I developed a small form which is showed below:
    
        
        Name

```
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="surname">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" name="surname">

    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telephone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone" name="telephone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The following is the jqueryscript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#frm_basic').validate({
        rules: {
            surname: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true,
            },
            name: {
                minlength: 5,
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
            },
            telephone : "validatePhone"
        },

        highlight: function(element) {
            var x=$(element).closest('.div').find("span");

            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('[class^="glyphicon"]').remove();
             $(element).closest('.form-group > div').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"'+' aria-hidden="true"'+'id="statushigh">' );
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) {
var y=$(element).closest('.div');
$(element).closest('.form-group').text(y.value);
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('[class^="glyphicon"]').remove();
             $(element).closest('.form-group > div').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"'+' aria-hidden="true"' +'id="statusun">' );
        },        
        success: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

     $.validator.addMethod("validatePhone", function(value) {
        var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
        if (filter.test(value)) {
            return true;
        }
     }, 
                'Please enter the right telephone number!'); 

});


</script>
```

Now, I want to show you which results I achieved:

[image: Form with validators]

I would like to have a style a little bit different, let me explain better:

I would like that the glyphicons can appear in the input field and not in a second line below the input. I believe who I have found the problem, when I change the class it add a new component/style:

[image: Code]

Besides, the 'element' variable who I used for applying the function 'closest' starts from which real element? What is the starting point?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
form .glyphicon {margin-top: -20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

I added the following piece of code:

```
errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.length) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        } 
    });
```

Comment: **Your solution makes no sense**. `error.insertAfter(element)` is exactly the same as `error.insertAfter(element)`. In other words, the same code is executed no matter what your `if` conditional decides. And `error.insertAfter(element)` is already the default `errorPlacement` code from the plugin!  So your `errorPlacement` function is  redundantly superfluous.  Remove it and the solution will work the same.  All you need to add is the new `errorElement` and `errorClass` options to fix your integration with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late answer but try to remove

> class="has-feedback"

from

```
<div form-group>
```

It works in my form.